# Why wont my div vertically align?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've written some code where when I click on an image it fades out and fades in a new div which should be vertically aligned. I use the same code as my logo which is originally `vertical-align: middle`, so I don't see the issue.

The code I'm using currently is this:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
margin: auto;
```

Here is the JSFiddle of a section of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/L79kte39/

Comment: Vertical align will work if the display type is table

Comment: @Sreevisakh not always as I know and know more of now thanks to the answer below posted by bigsby

Comment: I was talking about vertical-align:middle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vertical alignments in CSS can be tricky. Here's a good article I go back to when I haven't done it for a while:

- http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/

Apparently (read: supposedly), CSS has been adopted enough for the following to work fairly universally:

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[Source](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

Comment: Ahh that's awesome, I read through that briefly but I obviously didn't read that bit haha! Thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version. It uses `vertical-align`...with a lot of twists. It does *not* use transform, or any exact pixel widths. It does use one extra container.

The key is this:

```
.cod-valign:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
}
```

which creates an empty inline-block that fakes vertical-align (meant for text-row character placement) into thinking the current line of text contains a 0-character, 100%-tall string, at the center of the div. Then, the next element aligns next to it by also setting vertical-align. (I applied the image the same way)

It's tricky, but probably easier to understand if you remember that `vertical-align` was first intended for things like aligning large characters in a line of text in the correct way. (ie, if the first letter of a book chapter is large, does the rest of the text go at its top, or its bottom?)

http://jsfiddle.net/7qtLLakq/

Answer (score 0):

`#cod-options` would need a height to have it centered the way the logo is centered. Try `height:200px`